# Как разумнее: "врачъ Польских и врачь Галичаненко" или "врач Польских и врач Галичаненко"?

Tags: орфография

Примечание

1. В выражении "врачъ Польских и врачь Галичаненко" знак "ъ" указывает на мужской род тов. Польских, а знак "ь" указывает на женский род тов. Галичаненко.
2. В выражении "врач Польских и врач Галичаненко" нет указаний ни на род тов. Польских, ни род тов. Галичаненко.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы встретите человека, у которого возникают подобные вопросы, то посоветуйте ему перейти в параллельную реальность, где все проблемы решены с помощью разговорных суффиксов для обозначения рода: врач - врачиха, кондуктор - кондукторша.

Только с  профессоршей будьте осторожны (там возможны варианты), лучше и надежнее иметь дело с миллионершей.

Comment: Мягкий  знак  после  шипящего  не  указывает  на  половую  принадлежность.
Неужели  не  знаете ?

Comment: Dear bernard.

Я почти ничего не знаю и почти ничего не умею.